# Determine a locale change inherited from a parent element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, localization, web-component

I am trying to write a locale-aware [custom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements). To format its output, it looks up `lang` attributes on itself and its parent elements, falling back on the browser `navigator.language` UI localization.

```
format (d, m, s) {
    const lang = (this.closest('[lang]') || document.querySelector('html')).lang;

    let list = navigator.languages;
    try {
        list = Intl.getCanonicalLocales(lang);
    } catch (e) {}

    const format = new Intl.NumberFormat(list, {
        maximumFractionDigits: 2
    }).format;

    return `${d}° ${m}′ ${format(Math.round(s * 100) / 100)}″`;
}
```

That will give me the best possible information each time the component changes its value. But it doesn't cover cases where the `lang` attribute is changed during runtime. If the attribute is changed on the component itself, I can observe its change:

```
static get observedAttributes() { return ['lang']; }

attributeChangedCallback (name, oldValue, newValue) {
  if (name === 'lang') // trigger re-rendering
}
```

But how would I go about detecting change if it happens on a parent element or even the browser UI from which the setting is inherited?

A `MutationObserver` seems to be an awkward choice: I would have to attach it to *every* element in the parent chain, but can't assume that list to remain static - I would have to re-attach the Observer on every `adopted` or `connected` event of the component.

Comment: A MutationObserver is the only senssible way to observe a change of attribute X on element Y. Note that you do **not** have to set an MO on every element, you can add the MO at ``document`` level

Comment: That does not solve the awkwardness.1. A MO at root level would report attribute changes [on all elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit/subtree), even if they are not in the parent chain. 2. If the component was reused ten times in one website, one would end up with ten MOs on the same element observing the same attribute - or, when sharing it between the components, breaking the atomicity of the components.

Comment: 1. correct (*I usually end any awkward debate by typing ``.1+.2`` in the console to explain the Web world ain't perfect*) 2. put a marker/attribute on the ``body`` tag your MO was added.

Comment: 1. Ofcourse mutations inside shadowDOM are not caught: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995421/shadow-dom-know-when-dom-is-rendered-changed

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be that when the element is added to the page it recursively searches for the **first** parent/ancestor that has a `lang` attribute, adds a `MutationObserver` to it and responds to changes to that specific parent element.

IMO attempting to observe changes for all parents is an inefficient design choice and also sounds like an overkill feature.

I have not tried this personally, but to detect a change to the browser language, look into the [`languagechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/languagechange_event) event.